# How to permanently disable root-password prompt for recovery mode, RHEL6

Tags: centos, rhel, login, console, startup

In the rare cases that a RHEL or CentOS 6 system is prevented from booting by (for instance) an improper shutdown, or a forced fsck-check failure on boot, the console will prompt the user for a root password.

How do I disable the password check and drop directly to a root-shell?

*Unacceptable* answers:

- overriding `init` on kernel command line (ie, grub)
- linking / replacing /sbin/sulogin with /sbin/sushell. (This would work, but it would raise red flags with the security framework).
- booting from some other device

Comment: Many rc faults will invoke `rcS-emergency`, and adding `EMERGENCY=/bin/sushell` to `/etc/sysconfig/init` will make it run sushell. I don't know if this covers every conceivable fault that rc stuff can run into, though.

Comment: Ah, so the "environment" from rcS-emergency comes from /etc/sysconfig/init?  Post that as an aswer; I will test and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At several points in `rc.sysinit`, `rcS-emergency` will be run when there's a problem requiring administrator intervention, such as:

```
echo $"*** An error occurred during the file system check."
echo $"*** Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot"
echo $"*** when you leave the shell."
str=$"(Repair filesystem)"
PS1="$str \# # "; export PS1
[ "$SELINUX_STATE" = "1" ] && disable_selinux
start rcS-emergency
```

Here is the rcS-emergency script:

```
. /etc/sysconfig/init
plymouth --hide-splash || true
[ -z "$EMERGENCY" ] && EMERGENCY=/sbin/sulogin
exec $EMERGENCY
```

If you add `EMERGENCY=/bin/sushell` to `/etc/sysconfig/init`, it'll run sushell, which doesn't ask for a password.

Comment: Great job! Any chance you can answer this for systemd / rhel7 :D http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217383/how-to-permanently-disable-root-password-prompt-for-recovery-mode-rhel7