# How to permanently disable root-password prompt for recovery mode, RHEL7

Tags: centos, rhel, systemd, login, startup

*Note: I asked a similar quesiton concerning version 6 of these bundles [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217381/how-to-permanently-disable-root-password-prompt-for-recovery-mode-rhel6). Note that 7 uses systemd and may have a different implementation*

In the rare cases that a RHEL or CentOS 7 system is prevented from booting by (for instance) an improper shutdown, or a forced fsck-check failure on boot, the console will prompt the user for a root password.

How do I disable the password check and drop directly to a root-shell?

*Unacceptable* answers:

- overriding `init` on kernel command line (ie, grub)
- linking / replacing /sbin/sulogin with /sbin/sushell. (This would work, but it would raise red flags with the security framework).
- booting from some other device

Comment: Booting from a USB is also unacceptable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Systemd is working with **services** and **targets**. Targets is the equivalent of **runlevels**, services is the equivalent of **init scripts**.
Most of systemd configuration is located in `/usr/lib/systemd`, while standard init are in `/etc/{init.d,rc*.d,inittab}`.

When an issue kicks in during the boot process (default are **getty.target** or **graphical.target**, you can get them with `systemctl get-default`) systemd is switching to **emergency.target**.

This "emergency" target will in turn, load the file `emergency.service`. This service contains multiple lines, and among them:

```
...
[Service]
Environment=HOME=/root
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStartPre=-/bin/plymouth quit
ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo -e 'Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view\\nsystem logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" to try again\\nto boot into default mode.'
ExecStart=-/bin/sh -c "/sbin/sulogin; /usr/bin/systemctl --fail --no-block default"
...
```

We just need to replace the call to `/sbin/sulogin`:

```
ExecStart=-/bin/sh -c "/sbin/sushell; /usr/bin/systemctl --fail --no-block default"
```

And we will be dropped directly to a shell, instead of getting prompted for the password via sulogin. (We can use `/bin/sh`, but `/sbin/sushell` falls in line with the answers for CentOS6/RHEL6. In fact, `sushell` simply exec's `$SUSHELL` which defaults to `/bin/bash`.)

To make this change "permanent", ie, immune to `yum` updates, make the change to a copy of this file and place it in `/etc/systemd/system/`. Also, to make the "rescue mode" work the same way, replace the same line in `rescue.service`. Here's a shell/sed script to simplify the process:

```
for SERVICE in rescue emergency ; do 
   sed '/^ExecStart=/ s%"/sbin/sulogin;%"/sbin/sushell;%' /usr/lib/systemd/system/$SERVICE.service > /etc/systemd/system/$SERVICE.service
done
```

To test this, make sure the system is otherwise not in use, and tell `systemd` to switch to the `rescue` target:

```
systemctl rescue
```

This will close network connections and open a shell at the console. You can test with the `emergency` target, but that doesn't work quite as cleanly (For some reason) and may require a full reboot to come out of.

You can also test these from the boot-menu (grub). For testing the emergency mode, it's easy. Boot and when you get the menu, hit "e" to edit, and use the D-pad to navigate to the line beginning with `linux16` and append (hit `CTRL-A` to get to the end of the line) `emergency`:

```
linux16 ... emergency
```

For testing rescue mode, it's the same steps as above but you must be more explicit:

```
linux16 ... systemd.unit=rescue.target
```

Comment: Hum you're right, seem machinectl is only for VMs and Containers. I'm checking more in details about the systemd-ask-password systems with my local fedora & will edit the post as needed.

Comment: Ok, try this : edit `/usr/lib/systemd/emergency.service`. On line `"ExecStart=-/bin/sh -c "/sbin/sulogin; /usr/bin/systemctl --fail --no-block default"`, remove the `/sbin/sulogin ;` part. Tell me if that works, so I'll update the post.

Comment: Woops, maybe not remove it, but replace it by `/bin/sh`, or any other shell. And you can do the same replacement in `/usr/lib/systemd/rescue.service`

Comment: "You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits." Even on my own post ?  lol, some bugs for the devs :) Thanks for the test & edit !

Comment: In my test, I changed my /home mount, and it dropped to rescue. From what I saw (in this post: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=270936), "rescue" is the equivalent of Singleuser, "emergency" is the equivalent of init=/bin/sh.  We're all in for a  whole lot of tricks to learn with systemd :)

Comment: Great idea about changing mountpoints. I did the same for `/tmp` by simply modifying the fstype in `fstab` and on reboot, it dropped me to `emergency`'s service, not `rescue`. The grub-based "rescue" does not actually enter rescue mode on CentOS7. Answer edited again per RedHat docs and testing.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the direction of `emergency.service`: in my case, I **want** a password prompt and wasn't getting one on Ubuntu.  The man page states "if the root account is locked .... no password prompt is displayed and `sulogin` behaves as if the correct password were entered."

Comment: It is quite important to check that `/sbin/sushell` exists first. (It does on RHEL7, but not on Debian, where this answer is otherwise perfectly fine...)

Comment: Could you use `sulogin`'s `--force` option because that'll force it to work even if PW is locked. I think. I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Or, how about opening a shell as a regular user with login and `sudo` as `root` privileges?

Comment: Since [systemd 240](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/10397) you should actually just append the `ENABLE_FORCED_SULOGIN=1` variable to the *Environment* field.

Answer (score -3):

The method I used to follow for bypassing the root password and reach the root shell is by editing the init in grub (kernel line).

```
init=/bin/bash
```

Comment: Downvoted because I specifically mentioned overriding init is not an option. There are technical reasons this works poorly -- primarily because "init" does a lot "behind the scenes" to make the system somewhat usable.

Comment: With `init=/bin/bash`, you'll lose job control for the console, which means that Ctrl-C will not work. In an emergency situation, not being able to stop a command on your single console is a lot graver than "poor"...

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251228/5132 .