# I locked myself out of sudo and forgot the root password

Tags: debian

I really don't want to screw around with GRUB and everyone else's advice always involves me being a sudoer or knowing the root password

Comment: The only option that you have is to go into single-user mode and reset the root password. If you're going to use Linux then you need to know how to do that. The only other option is to blow everything away and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

Boot with a live disk.  Become root.  Mount your `/` partition someplace, and chroot to it.  Run `passwd` and set a new root user password.  Exit the chroot and reboot.

Comment: He doesn't need to boot from a live disc. He can enter single-user mode at boot and follow your steps.

Comment: Single user mode was superceded by emergency and rescue modes back in 1995.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392612/5132