# Accidentally did "systemctl set-default machines.target" on Fedora 29

Tags: command-line, fedora, systemctl

Accidentally gave the command

```
systemctl set-default machines.target
```

on Fedora 29 to reset back to GUI from cli and now my PC hangs on the boot logo. I want to know where the config file is so that I can boot with a live image and change the settings if it is in text format.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot the operating system into emergency mode, or rescue mode.
2. Log in.
3. Run `systemctl` to set the default to what you want.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on emergency and rescue mode bootstrap](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/emergency-and-rescue-mode-bootstrap.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392612/5132
- Lennart Poettering et al.. "[`emergency.target`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#emergency.target)".  *`systemd.special`*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al.. "[`rescue.target`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#rescue.target)".  *`systemd.special`*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- "[Booting into Emergency Mode](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#sec-Booting_to_Emergency_Mode)". *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 System Administrator's Guide*.  RedHat.
- "[Booting into Rescue Mode](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#sec-Booting_to_Rescue_Mode)". *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 System Administrator's Guide*.  RedHat.

Comment: Worth pointing out that "Setting up the root password is a mandatory part of the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 installation" does not apply to Fedora.  But the procedure to "reset" the root password should work equally well, to set a root password for the first time, so that you can log in to emergency/rescue mode.  (You cannot do so with any other user).

Answer (score 1):

In GRUB, you could just add the boot option

```
systemd.unit=graphical.target
```

or

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

to override the misconfigured default target and explicitly boot into either the GUI or CLI mode, and then use `systemctl set-default graphical.target` to reset the default target to normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/to/mounted/root/filesystem
rm etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

The configuration is stored as a symbolic link file.  When you delete the file in `etc`, it will go back to using the package default, which is stored at `lib/systemd/system/default.target`.