# Correct way to enter emergency mode during boot?

Tags: boot, fsck

What is the correct way to enter emergency mode during boot (without mounting any filesysstem) so I can run `fsck`?

`systemd.unit=emergency.target` as a kernel parameter dropped me into a shell though it did mount root.

If I replace the linux line in grub (on Arch) the following seems to work even though it shows some errors (device '' not found):

```
linux /vmlinuz-linux ro
```

This does not mount anything and allows me to run `fsck -f` on all drives.

Is there a better option or some documentation?

Comment: Linux must have a filesystem as it needs to run at least an initial process and the code for this process needs to be stored somewhere. These days it is usual to have an initial ramdisk. If the ramdisk image is not compiled into the kernel image then it is passed by grub using the initd command. What you did appears to be to tell the initial ramdisk not to switch to a root filesystem on the hard drive.

Comment: emergency.target should mount the root filesystem read-only. Can you verify it's doing that on your system?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick if I change `rw` to `ro` and add `systemd.unit=emergency.target` root is indeed mounted `ro`. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ways to trigger emergency or rescue modes have been the same across multiple system management systems since 1995, when they were invented.  systemd, the `system-manager` from the nosh toolset, and van Smoorenburg `init` all support these mechanisms.  They are copiously documented, and have been in books on Linux since at least 1997.

In the kernel command line, set by LILO, GRUB, or some other bootstrap loader:

- `-b` signifies emergency mode
- `-s` signifies rescue mode

van Smoorenburg `init`, where these were invented, supports the additional synonyms `S`, `single`, and `emergency`.
systemd and the nosh `system-manager` (actually `system-control init` which it passes the process #1 command-line on to) both support those synonyms and the further synonyms `s`, `1`, and `rescue`.

All of these are documented in their respective manuals.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on emergency and rescue mode bootstrap](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/emergency-and-rescue-mode-bootstrap.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Miquel van Smoorenburg and Michael Haardt (2004-07-29).  ["BOOTFLAGS"](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/sysvinit-core/init.8.en.html#BOOTFLAGS). `init`. *Linux System Administrator's Manual*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). ["System control subcommands"](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/system-control.xml#SYSTEMCONTROL).  `system-control`. *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2016). ["Kernel Command Line"](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#Kernel%20Command%20Line).
  `systemd`.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [Why booting into rescue mode menu doesn't do anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392591/5132)
- John Purcell (1999). *Linux: The Complete Reference*. Osborne McGraw-Hill.  ISBN 9781571762498.
- David A. Bandel (2000). *Linux: Security Toolkit*.  Wiley. ISBN 9780764546907.

Comment: Thank you. In addition to `-b` or `-s` it is also necessary to change/remove `rw` from the kernel parameters so it's possible for `fsck` to check the drive.